# Is there gap between polygons

Tags: polygon, area, polygons

A number of polygons, described by the coordinates of their vertexes, are supposed to fit together.

How can I check if they really fit together, without gap(s) in between?

Comment: By "without gaps" do you mean the result must be convex, or that the result must not have holes?

Comment: Probably you also want to know if the polygons overlap, or are twisted.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far (or read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and ask this question in another site)

Comment: I was thinking to match the vertexes together. Eliminate all vertexes that were duplicate (or triplicate, etc), those left should be the outer bound if there was no gap. Soon I found this algorithm had not account for some cases like a T-shape intersection of lines...

Answer (score 0):

If all polygons fit together, it would form a tight puzzle.  Think of 4 squares in a 2x2 formation.   If you have vertexes, you also have the edges.  If you think about it, all the edges would be duplicated, and removing all these duplicates would leave you with one polygon (a sequence of vertexes which loop back to itself.

Now you have to be careful when you deal with partial edges matching.  So what I would do is put all the edges in a bucket, then pull edges out one at a time and remove any overlay (which may be a partial overlay).  Then see what you are left with.

This should work even if the polygons are not convex.  I would make the assumption they are not self-intersecting or some other kind just to CYA.

Answer (score 0):

First check all the polygons are not overlapping.

Based on ergonaut suggestion, I figured after eliminating those paired up edges (after exact matches, see remark), those left could join together (by inspecting the coordinates of the ends) to form one or more polygons. 
1) if only one polygon left, it must be the outer bound of the combined area made from the polygons, and there is no gap;
2) if more than one polygon left, the largest one (A) could assumed to be the outer bound of the polygons, then if their areas added up then there is no gap.
3) if the polygons are discrete, the their total areas should be larger than A, and there is gap
4) If the polygons added up less than A, then there is also gap;

Anyone please comment if my thinking has loop hole and put up health criticism, many thanks.

Remark: the do exact matches reduce computation and serve the same for calculating area of polygon

Answer (score -1):

I would try plotting them in a program like Mathematica

Comment: But then you would have to visually confirm, and may miss tiny gaps.  You would still need an algorithm.  I wouldn't rely on visual confirmation to guarantee air-locks on the ISS, or water seals on an oil tanker.

Comment: You can devise a formula once they are plotted.  It would be hard to create a formula based on the coordinates alone.